# What to take from bootstraps responsive navbar in order to have a collapsable menu to add to my light weight website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, menu, jquery-plugins

I have created a fully functional mobile first responsive website. At this point I have not used any framework from sites like Bootstrap. I have very little knowledge of jquery but am trying to implement a similar collapsing menu that Bootstrap offers. I have a three bar menu icon so I am assuming I need a toggle feature that collapses a menu below the logo. The website I am creating is very light weight and I don't want to have to add the giant bootstrap responsive css file nor will it work with some of my naming conventions I already have in place. Is it possible to take just the collapse plugin from bootstrap and adapt it to my css, what steps should I go through if possible?
If anyone has knowledge or any other tutorials I could find to create this another way it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

below is my html setup. I don't know if this will help seeing of if I need to be adding css in order to get the collapse jquery to work.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <section class="grid sticky">
        <div class="container"> 
            <header class="grid twelve header">
                <a class="menuButton not-desktop not-tablet" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <div class="iconBar"></div>
                    <div class="iconBar"></div>
                    <div class="iconBar"></div>
                </a>
                <div class="logoHolder">
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo/ks_logo.svg"> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Main Nav, hidden below 768 px -->
                <nav class="mainNav  not-phone not-phoneSM">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>  
    </section>
<!-- Mobile Main Nav, called upon to relieve when screen is at 768 px -->
    <section class="not-desktop not-tablet">
            <header>
                <nav class="mobileMainNav nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
    </section>
```

`

Comment: Can you please post the code you are working with .. And yes you can just take the collapse plugin and use it in your project.

Comment: this is going to sound very dumb, I am a first time user on stackoverflow but how do I post my code? I had read by simply indenting I could add code but it is not allowing me.

Comment: ok, i figured it out. i posted my html this may help

Comment: this it not working, im not using any of bootstrap css only bootstrap collapse plugin. that may or may not have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the section you are referring to is

```
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">

  <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>

  <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
  <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

  <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You could always download the bootstrap css and bootstrap js, modify the css and then minify, doubt it will hurt your performance that much. Or you could extract the parts you need and incorporate into your own design. Without seeing your markup or the responsive css you have implemented kind of hard to advise any further

Comment: I tried implementing the collapse plugin from Bootstrap by implementing the HTML5 attributes data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" on the three bar menu icon and then placing the class="nav-collapse collapse" in nav that I want to be called upon to collapse. It didn't work. Again I am just learning jquery so I know very little but is the jquery only looking in the HTML for the data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" to be clicked upon and then retrieving and collapsing whatever is in  <div class="nav-collapse collapse"> or is it calling upon what is in the css? Thanks!

Comment: you probably want to grab some of the bootstrap JS aswell then (apologies, should have advised that)

Comment: oh no I had the JS linked to the page. it must not be working because its calling values from the bootstrap css and not just the html. would you know or have any suggestions of where to find a tutorial on this subject? i think i need a walk through to understand.

Comment: create a jsfiddle or at least post some of your code for the navbar

Comment: ok, i posted the two nav bars, one hides over 768px while the other shows and vise versa